# Problems importing QtGui from PyQt4

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, pyqt4

I have installed PyQt4 for python3 on Ubuntu 16.04LTS using these instructions:
https://gist.github.com/0x414A/8b64178e69d9f8331938

I experience no problems importing PyQt4 but when I try to import QtGui from PyQt4, I receive the following error:

`>>> from PyQt4 import QtGui
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: /home/yorka/Documents/BasicGUI/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyQt4/QtCore.so: undefined symbol: PyString_Type`

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try installing using pip command

sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt4